# how to correctly use guide_legend to control the number of rows of legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am ploting a figure in R with ggplot2. The legend in the figure has two rows but I want to unwrap them and make it in one row. I searched around and found that the `guide_legned()` is probably the way to go. I tried a couple of different ways and the only way does not give an error is like this:

```
fig <- ggplot(data, aes(y=y, x=x, shape=z))+
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0,1,2,3,4,6))+
  geom_abline('somestuff in here')+
  scale_fill_continuous(guide=guide_legend(nrow=1))+
  annotate('somestuff in here')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position='top',
        legend.key = element_blank())
```

However, the legend still turned out to be 2 rows. I am wondering why the `guide_legend(nrow=1)` is not working (even without an error). And what is the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `shape` aesthetic, but no `fill` aesthetic in your plot, so `scale_fill_continuous` isn't applicable here. It's the `shape` legend you want to format. Two options:

```
fig <- ggplot(data, aes(y=y, x=x, shape=z))+
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0,1,2,3,4,6), guide=guide_legend(nrow=1)+
  geom_abline('somestuff in here')+
  annotate('somestuff in here')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position='top',
        legend.key = element_blank())

fig <- ggplot(data, aes(y=y, x=x, shape=z))+
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0,1,2,3,4,6))+
  geom_abline('somestuff in here')+
  annotate('somestuff in here')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position='top',
        legend.key = element_blank()) +
  guides(shape=guide_legend(nrow=1))
```

Comment: Rather than changing in guides. Is it not possible to set all legends to be 1 row somewhere in the theme? Then make a theme and forget about it.